# Elastic Search Aggregations / Subtotals

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

Is it possible to generate subtotals?  I have an aggregation like this:

```
body_options: {
          aggs:{
            wbs_item_id: {
              terms: {
                field: "wbs_item_id"
              },
              aggs: {
                "total": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "total"
                  }
                },
                "invoiced": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "invoiced"
                  }
                },
                "forecast": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "forecast"
                  }
                },
                "committed": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "committed"
                  }
                },
                "accrued": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "accrued"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I also have a wbs_parent_id field that I want to sub total on.  Something Like:

1. Cars (5)

   - Ford (2)
   - Toyota (3)
2. Fruit (3)

   - Apples (2)
   - Oranges (1)

Can you do this with an Elastic Search aggregation?  If so how?

Comment: Could you please share your mapping? That's be helpful

Comment: I am using the Rails gem searchkick (https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) for ES.  I am going to see how I can produce that.  If I gather what you are asking I have an interger: wbs_item_id which is the key for the subtotals and I have a wbs_parent_id integer that is for the parent totals.